# To which word does "all" belong? (in my case)

Tags: phrases, translation, modifiers

In the following sentence, to which word (rescuers or hope) does 'all' belong?

*"Rescuers had abandoned all hope of finding any more survivors."*

If it belongs to the rescuers, why doesn't it appear just after the word 'Rescuers'?

and if it belongs to 'hope', why isn't it 'hopes'?

Comment: *Hope* can be used uncountably. Try to imagine *hope* as something fuzzy, homogenous, inseparable, the way *water* usually is. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, *all* is used for *hope* and not *rescuers.*

Secondly, the construction *all hope [singular]* is okay. As Damkerng says in his comment, *hope* is **also** an [uncountable noun.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hope_2) as used here. So, *all* with *hope* is okay.

There's also a song [*All Hope **is** Gone*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Hope_Is_Gone).

Answer (score 0):

"All hope" is a literal translation of "*ogni speranza*" from Dante's *Divine Comedy*.  According to the *[Divine Comedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=3mURAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&cad=0#v=onepage&q=lasciate&f=false)*, the following words are written on the gates of Hell:

> *Per me si va nella città dolente,*
>   *per me si va nell'eterno dolore,*
>   *per me si va tra la perduta gente.*
>   *Giustizia mosse il mio alto fattore,*
>   *fecemi la divina potestate,*
>   *la somma sapienza e il primo amore.*
>   *Dinanzi a me me non for cose create,*
>   *se non eterne, ed io eterno duro:*
>   *lasciate ogni speranza, voi, ch'entrate.*

"*Lasciate ogni speranza*" means "Abandon all hope".